# Tabitem reloading issue

Tags: wpf, tabitem

I'am facing a strange behavior with tabitems, so i would like to share it with you and i hope i get some explanations that helps me understand what's happening.

In Bref, my tabitems are initially empty, the content is set by clicking them. when clicking the first time the content is set in no time (0.0000006 ms), the second time it takes about 500 ms, so i started digging and i found out this : "tabitem.content = null;" this instruction takes around 400 ms (this happens only when tabitem.content != null), i am using it in order to clear the tabitem content and re-fill it.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance for the attention you will pay to my issue. FYI i am using Mahapps V0.14

Comment: Would not manually manage the `Content` and instead work with the `ItemTemplate` (header) and `ContentTemplate` (tab content).

Comment: hi @H.B thx for the quick reply, I forgot to tell that tabitems and their contents are created in code behind, i don't see how i am going to use ContentTemplate in code behind

Comment: You're not supposed to, you also are not supposed to create controls in code, that is the very reason why templates exist: To make the UI completely declarative without the need for imperative UI creation.

Comment: ok @H.B. i got your point and i agree, the problem is, the content depends on xml files content, i am using expanders as fieldset and gridview to show grid structures, users can add fieldsets, fields and grids as much as they want, how can i do a Template that can let users create dynamic screens

Comment: You translate your XML into objects, then you bind those objects to `ItemsControls` and the like and create `DataTemplates` according to the field they represent (`TextBox`, `ComboBox` etc).